# Flutter, complex SQLite DBs with many tables, is this best practice?

Tags: django, sqlite, flutter

Flutter newbie here afraid.

I have a small Django app (python) that I am porting over to a standalone Flutter app with no web back-end. I directly exported the SQL (DDL; about 300 lines worth) that specifies my SQL tables used in my Django app and use that in my flutter app (see below). I end up with ~8 tables and I can query these by just copy/pasting the Django SQL queries Django creates for me via it's [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/).

My question: is it best practice to have complex tables in mobile app development? I worry SQLite is not best suited for such complexity. But I feel it saves me time to reuse this already generated model structure and range of SQL queries.

Many thanks,
Andy.

```
initDb() async {
// Get a location using path_provider
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, "gear_log.db");

await deleteDatabase(path);

var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {

      String sql = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/db/schema.txt');
      for(var s in sql.split(";")) { //seems to be a max # characters for db.execute
        if(s.length > 5) { // catching any hidden characters at end of schema
          await db.execute(s + ';');
        }
      }

      // When creating the db, create the table

    });
return theDb;
```

}

Reusing Django generated SQL to retrieve data:

```
Future<List<Item>> getItems() async {
var dbClient = await db;
List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT "shoe_actualpair"."id", "shoe_actualpair"."created", "shoe_actualpair"."modified", "shoe_actualpair"."name", "shoe_actualpair"."shoe_id", "shoe_actualpair"."expires", "shoe_actualpair"."runner_id" FROM "shoe_actualpair" WHERE "shoe_actualpair"."runner_id" = 1 ORDER BY "shoe_actualpair"."modified" DESC, "shoe_actualpair"."created" DESC');
List<Item> employees = new List();
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  employees.add(Item.fromMap(list[i]));
}
return employees;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use jaguar ORM. https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_orm

I am using it in a an app with both one-one, one-many and many-many relationships.

For sqlite (sqflite), you also need this adapter in your flutter app:
https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_orm/tree/master/sqflite